# How to make regex optional at specific position?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have regex list that check for multiple column values. Columns are separated by tab delimiter. I have 32 columns that are required and another 12 optional. So if my file has 44 columns in total I would need to run entire list but if I have 32 only then I would like to make rest of the list optional. Here is my regex:

```
<cfset myRegex = "^[A-Za-z '-]{1,20}\t[A-Za-z '-]{1,20}\t(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}\t([M|F])\t(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|PK)\t[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}\t[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}\t\d{10}(\t[^\t]*){22}\t([0-9]{4})\t([^\t]*)\t([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t([A-Za-z0-9 '-.;]{1,100}|NULL)\t([A-Za-z '-]{1,50}|NULL)\t(\b([A-Z]{2})\b|NULL)\t(\b\d{5}(-\d{4})?\b|NULL)\t(\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t(\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t(\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t(\d+|NULL)\t([A-Za-z '-]{1,50}|NULL)\t((([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}|NULL)\r?$">
```

I'm wondering if I can make these extra columns optional in my list that way I can use them only if I have 44 columns. I tried to put `?` after each optional column but that did not work, my regex was outputting false in that case.

Here is updated regex with the optional columns in (\t):

```
<cfset fileRegex = "^[A-Za-z '-]{1,20}\t[A-Za-z '-]{1,20}\t(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}\t([M|F])\t(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|PK)\t[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}\t[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}\t\d{10}(\t[^\t]*){22}\t([0-9]{4})\t(([^\t]*)\t)?(([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z0-9 '-.;]{1,100}|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z '-]{1,50}|NULL)\t)?((\b([A-Z]{2})\b|NULL)\t(\b\d{5}(-\d{4})?\b|NULL)\t)?((\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t)?((\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t)?((\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t)?((\d+|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z '-]{1,50}|NULL)\t)?(((([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}|NULL))?\r?$">
```

This did not work as well.

Example with the data:

```
<cfset myData = "Ruiz   John    09/01/1984  M   00  Red Star    player  3345678879  0   0   0   0   0   1                   0   0   0       0   0   0   0   0       19234   1011    0089    01">

<cfif REFind(fileRegex,myData,true) GT 0>
    true<br>
<cfelse>
    false<br>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Your regex contains 24 `\t`. Actually, it is not clear what you need, and the pattern is too long and impossible to debug without a sample string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you take a better look after the 7th \t I have (\t[^\t]*){22} that represents 22 columns that should not contain \t inside. I did not use any strict validation on those fields. Just making sure that they do not have tab.

Comment: Try the expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/FJVdso/1). I assume your regex is almost right (really, I can't know how to debug it properly, no one but you can), I just found a place where `\t` is placed into the obligatory group, while it must be part of the optional one (perhaps,I do not have all necessart data).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tested and works fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fixed regex is

```
^[A-Za-z '-]{1,20}\t[A-Za-z '-]{1,20}\t(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}\t([M|F])\t(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|PK)\t[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}\t[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}\t\d{10}(\t[^\t]*){22}\t([0-9]{4})\t[^\t]*(\t([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z0-9 '-.;]{1,100}|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z '-]{1,50}|NULL)\t)?((\b([A-Z]{2})\b|NULL)\t(\b\d{5}(-\d{4})?\b|NULL)\t)?((\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t)?((\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t)?((\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})|NULL)\t)?((\d+|NULL)\t)?(([A-Za-z '-]{1,50}|NULL)\t)?(((([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}|NULL))?\r?$
```

The [regex demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/FJVdso/2).

There was one `\t` that needed moving from `(([^\t]*)\t)?` to the `(([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t)?` (=> `(\t([A-Za-z '-]{1,20}|NULL)\t)?`) optional group.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the optional column's regex (and one \t) with parenthesis () and then add ? at the end

Comment: (and one \t)? should I include \t after the each column/regex?

Comment: yes, because if you make the regex part optional, you will end up with two tabs (\t)

Comment: I updated my question. I tried that but did not work. Maybe I have something wrong in my code.

Comment: do you have a set of data where we can test the regex ?

Comment: I will put line of code with the data in my question.